# Parse file with tab “\t” delimiter to get specific tab

Tags: java, regex, hashmap, hashtable, tokenize

I have a text file which contains data separated by "\t". I would like to parse this file to get Coulmn-1 and Coulmn-2. The format of the file as follow:

```
    Coulmn-1         Coulmn-2    Coulmn-3     Coulmn-4
        the               -       (A0*           *
    average               -          *           *
      price               -          *           *
         of               -          *           *
          a               -          *           *
     gallon               -          *           *
         of               -          *           *
   gasoline               -         *)           * 
        has               -          *           *
     jumped          jumped       (V*)           *
```

What I would like to do is parse this file and get the the the content of Coulmn-2 first. I will use it as a key in "Hashtable" and then check Coulmn-3. The value of the key will be the the content of column-1. For example: The key in the example I gave will be jumped, while the value will be "the average price of a gallon of gasoline". To get this value I have to check Coulmn-3. The value will start from "(A0*" till "*)"

I know how to read parse files, but I would like to know how to start. Should I get read line by line and get all these information together, or should I read the file more than one time to get these information.Thanks,,

Comment: This is a tab-delimited CSV file. I'd use a CSV parser that lets you change the delimiter literal, like OpenCSV.

Comment: @TheHeadRush - The `C` in CSV stands for _"comma"_; if it's "tab-delimited" (separated) not comma-separated it's not a CSV, it's a [TSV](http://www.fileformat.info/format/tsv/) file. But I agree an already-written package is the way to go.

Comment: Semantics. In my experience, more people are familiar with the term CSV than TSV, so it is easier to explain using the more familiar term. But technically, you are correct and i am incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

I would simply parse it line by line, skipping any optional headers, split it into it's relevant columns and then feed the columns to a handler method. 
the split method of string can work for you in that, though regular expressions might work better if you only want a specific column